# Which one is RSA encryption algorithm?

Tags: encryption, rsa

I searched in the internet for *Online RSA calculator* and also for *RSA algorithm example* and I found [this online RSA calculator tool](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~introcs/Fa11/notes/10.1_Cryptography/RSA_Express_EncryptDecrypt.html)  and this [site that mention the algorithm](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mitra/honors/soln.html) as below :

> RSA Algorithm Example
>
> Choose p = 3 and q = 11 Compute n = p * q = 3 * 11 = 33 Compute φ(n) =
>   (p - 1) * (q - 1) = 2 * 10 = 20 Choose e such that 1 < e < φ(n) and e
>   and n are coprime.
>
> Let e = 7 Compute a value for d such that (d * e) %
>   φ(n) = 1. One solution is d = 3 [(3 * 7) % 20 = 1]
>
> Public key is (e,n) => (7, 33)
>
> Private key is (d, n) => (3, 33)
>
> The encryption of m = 2
>   is c = 2^7 % 33 = 29
>
> The decryption of c = 29 is m = 29^3 % 33 = 2

As I want to test another example by myself, I select another pair for *p* and *q* and I did the above steps :

```
p=4259 and q=6053 ==> n=p*q=25779727
φ(n)=(p-1)*(q-1)=25769416
And as GCD(23421481,25779727)=1, I select e=23421481
Now if I want to encrypt '1',  its encryption is (1^23421481)%25779727
```

It it obviously that `(1^23421481)%25779727=1`

But when I use the online calculator tool, this is output :

[image]

As you see, it returns `10098474` as the encryption value of `1`!

**Q1:** Why? What's wrong with the steps that I done manually to calculate encryption value?

**Q2:** How this site calculate this expression for another number(except 1)? I think `2^23421481` is a really large number for this kind of online tool to calculate in a part of second!! (I tried to calculate 2^23421481 using wolfram-alpha. even this big site returns time out!) :D

Comment: Likely, especially since it says "Plaintext Message to encode" - what you enter in the form is not converted to an integer but remaining as text.  1 in Unicode or UTF-8 does not translate to the literal number 1, it's equivalent to two bytes 0x00 0x31 for Unicode or merely the single byte 0x31 for UTF-8.

Comment: @ultrasawblade You should put that as the answer (because it is the answer, as 0x31 = 49 is what's under "Plaintext Message in numeric form")

Comment: @ultrasawblade How I can try(Check) it? Is there any online-tool that can calculate this expression? I couldn't receive any answer in Wolfram-Alpha! It returns "Time Out!" I even wrote a python script to calculate it, But it goes to 'Not Responding' state.